# Data structure for finding lines in between two heights

Tags: javascript, typescript, data-structures, binary-search-tree, text-editor

I am implementing a simple application, where I have a bunch of lineHeights stored like so:

```
lineHeights = [2, 4, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, /* ... */]
```

Now given two heights, `a` and `b` I need to find the range of lines in between `a` and `b`

For example, if the heights are `[2, 2, 4, 5, 2]`, then the range of lines in between `3` and `7` would be `[1, 2]` as lines `1` to `2` are contained by the range of heights given.

A naive implementation would be to store the lines as an array, and travel up the array to see which lines are in between the heights given, as shown in the following pseudo code (which I haven't tested, but I hope you can understand what I'm showing):

```
get_line_range_between_heights (lines start_height end_height)
  index = 0
  height = 0
  while true
    height = height + lines[index]
    if height >= start_height
      break
    index = index + 1
  result_ranges = [index]
  while true
    height = height + lines[index]
    if height >= end_height
      break
    index = index + 1
  push index into result_ranges
  return result_ranges
```

However, the simple implementation comes at a cost - while inserting and removing heights is fast, querying becomes an `O(n)` operation, where `n` is the number of lines

So my question is - is there a sort of data structure (for example something like a binary search tree) which ideally would have insert, delete and search (for lines in between two heights) operations in `O(n)` or better, which is specialised for this sort of problem (ideally with an implementation, or a link to one)?

Comment: please add some more use cases and the algo behind.

Comment: @NinaScholz, seems to be python

Comment: That sounds like `elements from array whose sum is between a and b` and the result is represented by indexes of those elements.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding something; why in your example is [1, 2] between 3 and 7, as opposed to [4, 5]?

Comment: Yes, a balanced binary search tree will do exactly what you need. Also store the combined height of all children in every node to quickly compute the indices, similar to how [finger trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_tree) do it.

Comment: question is unclear. plz elaborate line height and range, what are they? and how are they computed ?

Comment: @ShivajiVarma seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @NinaScholz its not any language - its pseudocode

Comment: @series0ne its [1, 2] because the lines between heights 3 and 7 is 1 and 2. Each item in the array is the height of the individual line, so the offset of an item in the array given is the sum of all the heights before it.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the help! One question though - don't balanced search trees need a key, and if I use the index of the line as the key then insert and delete operations will be `O(n)`, right?

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff If you want to access them by index as well, you kinda need two "keys": one for the size (number of leafs) of the node subtree (which sums up to the index) and one for the height (combined heights of the leafs) of the node subtree (which sum up to the y position of the lines)

Comment: @Bergi thanks, but if you insert heights into the middle of the tree then would it be `O(n)` or `O(logn)` (as in would you have to reindex half the items)

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff No, you don't store indices. You only store the size, which sums up to indices *when you traverse* the tree.

Comment: @Bergi oh, I understand. But for example if I use a self-balancing binary search tree, for example a rbtree or a splay tree, then what would I use as the key?

Comment: @GuyWhoKnowsStuff you have to compute the key (that you want to compare against) on the fly. There is no absolute information stored in the nodes.

Comment: Also have a look at [skip lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)